# Tortoise SVN. Certain sub-directories won't update from main directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're using SVN Tortoise at work, and when I do an update from the main directory, it seems to ignore files in particular sub-directories.  However, if I do an update from said sub-directories, it will pull down the updated files.  Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdirectories may not be where they actually belong. If on the server, you've got `A/B` and `A/B/C`, perhaps you're checked `C` out under `A`, and then `C` is being ignored when `A` is updated.